# Loading custom php file in Laravel without composer dump-autoload

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new in Laravel. I've been followed few threads of how to load custom php library to Laravel 4,2 without `dump autoload`. So far I'm unable or I calling the function incorrect.

What I have so far is:

1. I file `autoload_classmap.php` I've added my class

   `'ImageResize' => $baseDir . '/app/libraries/ImageResize.php',`
2. In file `autoload_static.php` I've added

   `'ImageResize' => __DIR__ . '/../..' . '/app/libraries/ImageResize.php',`

Then in my controller in the function where I want to be shown this class I've tried like this

```
public function upload() {

$FmyFunction1 = new \ImageResize(); 
    return View::make('site.admin.upload', [
        'FmyFunction1' => $FmyFunction1
    ]);
}
```

Result is when I try to load `/upload` page I've got error:

> 'Class 'ImageResize' not found'

Is this error from wrong calling the class and/or error from not include correctly the class in Laravel at all? Can anyone help me?

ps. The reason I can't use dump autoload is because I have only ftp access to the host and I don't have SSH...

Comment: If you go into that file, is the class name exactly `ImageResize` and there is no namespace?  It's possible the class is named something differently than the file.

Comment: Yes, the file is starting like: `class ImageResize { .... }`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add your namespace to the autoloader like this :

```
$loader = require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$loader->add('NameSpace', 'Path to directory'); // PSR-0 loading
$loader->addPsr4('NameSpace\\', 'Path to directory'); // PSR-4 loading
```

Doc : https://getcomposer.org/apidoc/1.0.0/Composer/Autoload/ClassLoader.html#method_add

---

The code needs to be added in the bootstrap.php file : you need to extend the base autoloader which is loaded with this line : `require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';`

replace this line with `$loader = require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';` and add your custom namespace to the autoloader.

Comment: Sorry but in which file I should add this?

Comment: you can add it in `bootstrap/autoload.php` or in your `index.php`. It needs to be in a file loaded before your controller

Comment: I've added it to `index.php` in `public` dir and before `$app->run();` .. stil class not found error.

Comment: Sorry for my late response.. I was a bit away. Just a question. Where is `'Path to directory'` do I need to add full path there? like `/var/wwwhtml/mysite/app/libraries/ImageResize.php`

Comment: "path to directory" is the path to the base directory of your namespace. you can either use a full path or a relative path.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PSR-4 autoloading](https://laracasts.com/lessons/psr-4-autoloading).

With `PSR-0/PSR-4`, you don't have to dump-autoload when you add or update a class.

Comment: PSR-4 require dump auotload in order to load the new file in `vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php` Also in video you send at the end he did it..